# Display.getInstance().createSoftWeakRef(...) usage

Tags: codenameone

In which cases `Display.getInstance().createSoftWeakRef(Object o)` can be useful? Thanks for the explanation.

Javadoc:
https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Display.html#createSoftWeakRef-java.lang.Object-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching. We use it extensively inside Codename One to cache things that might cause a memory leak otherwise e.g. images. This reduces memory thrashing as some images might avoid GC collection if they are still needed before a GC cycle occurs.

A good example for this is in `EncodedImage` which is very efficient. It stores only the compressed PNG/JPEG data in a hard reference but loads the image when we need it. This reference is saved in a weak/soft reference. Notice that this class can be in "locked" mode which stores the reference as a hard reference (that won't be GC'd) for performance reasons.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the example. Do you think that normally I can ignore this method (because it’s used internally by Codename One) or there are cases in which I can directly use it? I mean: efficient image caching is already implemented by Encoded Image, in which other cases I can need caching in an app?

Comment: I can't recall cases where I needed that for a standard app.